# Spring boot test: @Sql annotation Unable to locate sql files placed in src/test/resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I didn't want to load the entire Spring Boot configuration for unit-testing my `DAO` layer, and therefore created a nested configuration class to **suppress default configurations**. But when I try to specify SQL scripts for it to run before tests, its unable to find them.

Here's the code:

```
package com.test.customer.controller;
..
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@JdbcTest
@Sql({"data.sql"})
public class InterviewInformationControllerTest {

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfiguration{

    }

    @Test
    public void testCustomer() {
        // code
    }

}
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [com/test/customer/controller/data.sql]; 
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
class path resource [com/test/customer/controller/data.sql] 
cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I've tried placing the file at both `src/main/resources` (not preferred) as well as at `src/test/resources` (which I prefer)

Note: I'm running the Unit test from inside Eclipse by doing `Run as -> JUnit test`.

**Edit**: Added the `static` keyword to the configuration class

Answer (score 24, accepted):

your inner configuration class will not work [unless you add a static keyword before its definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142962/spring-boot-test-unable-to-instantiate-inner-configuration-class/55143019#55143019). However you should know that for the @Sql annotation

> Path Resource Semantics
>
> Each path will be interpreted as a Spring Resource. A plain path — for
>   example, "schema.sql" — will be treated as a classpath resource that
>   is relative to the package in which the test class is defined. A path
>   starting with a slash will be treated as an absolute classpath
>   resource, for example: "/org/example/schema.sql". A path which
>   references a URL (e.g., a path prefixed with classpath:, file:, http:,
>   etc.) will be loaded using the specified resource protocol.

So try to prefix the value inside `@Sql` with `classpath:` like this :

```
@Sql(scripts={"classpath:data.sql"})
```

Good luck!

Comment: Will **src/main/resources**  and **src/test/resources** both be included in the classpath by default?

Comment: Sometimes vanilla java don't add the src/main/resources to the classpath depending on the runner that you are using

Comment: +1 for path resource semantics. @Daud, you may want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669393/override-default-spring-boot-application-properties-settings-in-junit-test/60296719#60296719) for your question on resources.

Answer (score 3):

Check your `out` directory of the module. While creating directory in resources, if you have named it directly with the namespace like `com.gakshintala.bookmybook`, it takes that name completely as the directory name, so the `out` also contains this directory under `resources` with name `com.gakshintala.bookmybook`. PFB right vs wrong. The top is right and bottom is wrong.

[image]
[image]

Spring always looks for nested directory resources->com->gakshintala->bookmybook.
So create that directory structure.